# Limit JQuery so HTML code only shows a limited number of times

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML code on a page and I am trying to add a small piece of html after every feed item. However I have a numerous amount of feed items but only want the html to show three times only.

The HTML:

```
<div class="wp_rss_retriever">
  <ul class="wp_rss_retriever_list">
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/uncategorized/man-united-ready-to-smash-transfer-record-to-sign-star-striker/" title="Man United ready to smash transfer record to sign star striker">Man United ready to smash transfer record to sign star striker</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 12:29 pm</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/fenerbahce-plan-bid-for-manchester-united-ace-mata/" title="Fenerbahce plan bid for Manchester United ace Mata">Fenerbahce plan bid for Manchester United ace Mata</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 12:15 pm</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/united-arsenal-target-morata-premier-league-would-suit-me/" title="Manchester United, Arsenal target Morata: Premier League would suit me">Manchester United, Arsenal target Morata: Premier League would suit me</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 11:55 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/manchester-united-rival-arsenal-liverpool-for-juventus-striker-morata/" title="Manchester United rival Arsenal, Liverpool for Juventus striker Morata">Manchester United rival Arsenal, Liverpool for Juventus striker Morata</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 11:48 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/germany-coach-low-bastian-schweinsteiger-will-make-euros/" title="Germany coach Low: Bastian Schweinsteiger will make Euros">Germany coach Low: Bastian Schweinsteiger will make Euros</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 11:44 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/toni-kroos-upset-for-schweinsteiger-over-knee-setback/" title="Toni Kroos upset for Schweinsteiger over knee setback">Toni Kroos upset for Schweinsteiger over knee setback</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 11:39 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/uncategorized/manchester-united-youth-rankings-2016-10-joe-riley/" title="Manchester United Youth Rankings 2016 #10 -Joe Riley">Manchester United Youth Rankings 2016 #10 -Joe Riley</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 11:38 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/revealed-anthony-martial-matches-ronaldo-goalscoring-exploits/" title="REVEALED: Anthony Martial matches Ronaldo goalscoring exploits">REVEALED: Anthony Martial matches Ronaldo goalscoring exploits</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 11:34 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/uncategorized/manchester-united-transfer-news-alvaro-morata-jose-mourinho-plan-top-rumours/" title="Manchester United Transfer News: Alvaro Morata, Jose Mourinho Plan, Top Rumours">Manchester United Transfer News: Alvaro Morata, Jose Mourinho Plan, Top Rumours</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 11:21 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/manchester-united-player-insists-squad-dont-talk-about-van-gaal-speculation/" title="Manchester United player insists squad don&#039;t talk about Van Gaal speculation">Manchester United player insists squad don&#039;t talk about Van Gaal speculation</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 11:10 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/ed-woodwards-right-hand-man-praises-under-fire-manchester-united-manager-louis-van-gaal/" title="Ed Woodward&#039;s right-hand man praises under-fire Manchester United manager Louis van Gaal">Ed Woodward&#039;s right-hand man praises under-fire Manchester United manager Louis van Gaal</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 10:20 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/felipe-anderson-confirms-united-bid/" title="Felipe Anderson confirms United bid">Felipe Anderson confirms United bid</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 9:43 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper"><a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/the-race-for-top-four-predictions/" title="The race for top four: Predictions">The race for top four: Predictions</a>
        <div class="wp_rss_retriever_container">
          <div class="wp_rss_retriever_metadata"><span class="wp_rss_retriever_date">Published: March 25, 2016 - 9:39 am</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wp_rss_retriever_item">
      <div class="wp_rss_retriever_item_wrapper">
        <a class="wp_rss_retriever_title" target="_blank" href="http://footballnewsdaily.net/manchester-united/bryan-robson-seeks-to-recover-375000-in-lost-investments/"
```

This is the JQuery code i am using to add a piece of html after every feed item. It works fine but I am struggling to find a way to modify it so the html only shows three times.

```
 $(function() {

  $("<p>Test</p>").insertAfter(".wp_rss_retriever_container");
})
```

Comment: Have you read over the 'How do I ask a good question?'-section in the help center? This doesn't seem to be some short relevant code...

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the elements and then do a hard check against how many times the loop has occurred.

```
$('.wp_rss_retriever_container').each(function(index, element){
    if(index < 3){
        $(this).after('<p>Test</p>');
    }
});
```

I think this is what you're attempting to achieve.

Comment: Might as well just select `.wp_rss_retriever_container:lt(3)` and not have to worry about looking at the index or looping through the rest of the elements after we are done with the first 3.